# reading variables simultaneously with 'fgets'

Tags: c++

I am unable to understand the working of the following code. fgets() doesnt discard a newline unlike gets(). So when I run the program, why does it always skip the second input?

Thanks :)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    char m[100], n[100];
    int dummy;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
       fgets(m, 50, stdin);
       fgets(n, 50, stdin);
       cout<<m<<n;
    }

}
```

Comment: Every time you mix C and C++ like this, a random cat dies a horribly painful death. It could be yours next time, do you really want to risk that?

Comment: Even when I used just C, the result was still the same. Am I going wrong somewhere?

https://ideone.com/DHTKv1

Comment: If you need with C, tag the question as C, delete the `#include <iostream> using namespace std;` lines, and change `cstdio` with `stdio.h`

Comment: As you can see, you where really programming in C, not C++

Comment: I just wanted to understand the working of fgets. The working should remain the same whether we use it in C or C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` is defined to stop reading whenever a *new-line* is found, and it's doing exactly what it is supposed to.

The problem with your snippet is that `scanf` invoked with *"%d"* as the format-specifier won't read anything that appears after the digits read.

---

Imagine our input being the below, where `<new-line>` denotes a *new-line* character:

```
123<new-line>
hello world<new-line>
olleh dlrow
```

After `scanf` has done it's work the input stream will consist of the following

```
<new-line>
hello world<new-line>
olleh world
```

Notice that the *new-line* after `123` hasn't been read, this means that your first call to `fgets` will read that single character (ie. the *new-line*) and return.